# How to live stream a local video using FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, stream, udp, vlc

I have been trying to stream local video on VLC using the FFmpeg library like this:

```
$ ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -v 0 -vcodec mpeg4 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:23000
```

I have not been able to stream the file on VLC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My guess is that you are trying to play in VLC using the URL `udp://127.0.0.1:23000` as you have it in the FFmpeg command.
In VLC, try using `udp://@:23000` instead.

Answer (score 26):

In the first terminal:

```
$ ffmpeg -i sample.mp4 -v 0 -vcodec mpeg4 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:23000
```

Open a second terminal and use:

```
$ ffplay udp://127.0.0.1:23000
```

Answer (score 0):

It works, but it's ugly on VLC.

On MacOS Catalina with:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i "0" -f mpeg1video -b 200k -r 30 -vf scale=640:360 udp://127.0.0.1:5555
```

and it works well with:

```
ffplay -fflags nobuffer -flags low_delay -framedrop -strict experimental   udp://127.0.0.1:5555
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with @Omy's answer be sure to add [`-re`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) before the input to ensure realtime (normal) livestreaming than sending too many UDP payloads at once. For instance,

```
ffmpeg -re -i sample.mp4 -v 0 -vcodec mpeg4 -f mpegts udp://127.0.0.1:23000
```